# Weights in Numpy Neural Net Not Updating, Error is Static

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, backpropagation

I'm trying to build a neural network on the Mnist dataset for a HW assignment. I'm not asking anyone to DO the assignment for me, I'm just having trouble figuring out why the Training accuracy and Test Accuracy seem to be static for every epoch?

It's as if my way of updating weights is not working.

```
Epoch: 0, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
Epoch: 1, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
Epoch: 2, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
Epoch: 3, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
.
.
.
```

However, when I run the actual forward and backprop lines in a loop without any 'fluff' of classes or methods the cost goes down. I just can't seem to get it working in the current class setup.

I've tried building my own methods that pass the weights and biases between the backprop and feed-forward methods explicitly, however, those changes haven't done anything to fix this gradient descent issue.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the definition of the backprop method in the NeuralNetwork class **below**. I've been struggling to find a way to update the weights by accessing the weight and bias variables in the main training loop.

```
def backward(self, Y_hat, Y):
        '''
        Backward pass through network. Update parameters 

        INPUT
            Y_hat: Network predicted 
                shape: (?, 10)

            Y: Correct target
                shape: (?, 10)

        RETURN 
            cost: calculate J for errors 
                type: (float)

        '''

        #Naked Backprop
        dJ_dZ2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dW2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X2), dJ_dZ2)
        dJ_db2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dX2 =  np.matmul(dJ_db2, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dX2 * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        inner_mat = np.matmul(Y-Y_hat,np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dW1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X),inner_mat) * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        dJ_db1 = np.matmul(Y - Y_hat, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2)) * d_sigmoid(Z1)

        lr = 0.1

        # weight updates here
        #just line 'em up and do lr * the dJ_.. vars you found above
        NeuralNetwork.W2 = NeuralNetwork.W2 - lr * dJ_dW2
        NeuralNetwork.b2 = NeuralNetwork.b2 - lr * dJ_db2
        NeuralNetwork.W1 = NeuralNetwork.W1 - lr * dJ_dW1
        NeuralNetwork.b1 = NeuralNetwork.b1 - lr * dJ_db1

        # calculate the cost
        cost = -1 * np.sum(Y * np.log(Y_hat))

        # calc gradients

        # weight updates

        return cost#, W1, W2, b1, b2
```

I'm really at a loss here, any help is appreciated!

Full code is shown here...

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist

np.random.seed(0)

"""### Load MNIST Dataset"""

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X = x_train[0].reshape(1,-1)/255.; Y = y_train[0]
zeros = np.zeros(10); zeros[Y] = 1
Y = zeros

#Here we implement the forward pass for the network using the single example, $X$, from above

### Initialize weights and Biases

num_hidden_nodes = 200 
num_classes = 10

# init weights
#first set of weights (these are what the input matrix is multiplied by)
W1 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(784,num_hidden_nodes))
#this is the first bias layer and i think it's a 200 dimensional vector of the biases that go into each neuron before the sigmoid function.
b1 = np.zeros((1,num_hidden_nodes))

#again this are the weights for the 2nd layer that are multiplied by the activation output of the 1st layer
W2 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(num_hidden_nodes,num_classes))
#these are the biases that are added to each neuron before the final softmax activation.
b2 = np.zeros((1,num_classes))


# multiply input with weights
Z1 = np.add(np.matmul(X,W1), b1)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(- z))

def d_sigmoid(g):
    return sigmoid(g) * (1. - sigmoid(g))

# activation function of Z1
X2 = sigmoid(Z1)


Z2 = np.add(np.matmul(X2,W2), b2)

# softmax
def softmax(z):
    # subracting the max adds numerical stability
    shiftx = z - np.max(z)
    exps = np.exp(shiftx)
    return exps / np.sum(exps)

def d_softmax(Y_hat, Y):
    return Y_hat - Y

# the hypothesis, 
Y_hat = softmax(Z2)

"""Initially the network guesses all categories equally. As we perform backprop the network will get better at discerning images and their categories."""


"""### Calculate Cost"""

cost = -1 * np.sum(Y * np.log(Y_hat))


#so i think the main thing here is like a nested chain rule thing, where we find the change in the cost with respec to each 
# set of matrix weights and biases?

#here is probably the order of how we do things based on whats in math below...
'''
1. find the partial deriv of the cost function with respect to the output of the second layer, without the softmax it looks like for some reason?
2. find the partial deriv of the cost function with respect to the weights of the second layer, which is dope cause we can re-use the partial deriv from step 1
3. this one I know intuitively we're looking for the parial deriv of cost with respect to the bias term of the second layer, but how TF does that math translate into 
numpy? is that the same y_hat - Y from the first step? where is there anyother Y_hat - y?
4. This is also confusing cause I know where to get the weights for layer 2 from and how to transpose them, but again, where is the Y_hat - Y?
5. Here we take the missing partial deriv from step 4 and multiply it by the d_sigmoid function of the first layer outputs before activations.
6. In this step we multiply the first layer weights (transposed) by the var from 5
7. And this is weird too, this just seems like the same step as number 5 repeated for some reason but with y-y_hat instead of y_hat-y
'''
#look at tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qYtIveJ6hU
#I think the most backprop layer steps are fine without biases but how do we find the bias derivatives

#maybe just the hypothesis matrix minus the actual y matrix?
dJ_dZ2 = Y_hat - Y


#find partial deriv of cost w respect to 2nd layer weights
dJ_dW2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X2), dJ_dZ2)


#finding the partial deriv of cost with respect to the 2nd layer biases
#I'm still not 100% sure why this is here and why it works out to Y_hat - Y
dJ_db2 = Y_hat - Y


#finding the partial deriv of cost with respect to 2nd layer inputs
dJ_dX2 =  np.matmul(dJ_db2, np.transpose(W2))



#finding the partial deriv of cost with respect to Activation of layer 1
dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dX2 * d_sigmoid(Z1)



#y-yhat matmul 2nd layer weights
#I added the transpose to the W2 var because the matrices were not compaible sizes without it
inner_mat = np.matmul(Y-Y_hat,np.transpose(W2))
dJ_dW1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X),inner_mat) * d_sigmoid(Z1)


class NeuralNetwork:
    # set learning rate
    lr = 0.01

    # init weights
    W1 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(784,num_hidden_nodes))
    b1 = np.zeros((1,num_hidden_nodes))

    W2 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(num_hidden_nodes,num_classes))
    b2 = np.zeros((1,num_classes))


    def __init__(self, num_hidden_nodes, num_classes, lr=0.01):
        '''
        # set learning rate
        lr = lr

        # init weights
        W1 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(784,num_hidden_nodes))
        b1 = np.zeros((1,num_hidden_nodes))

        W2 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(num_hidden_nodes,num_classes))
        b2 = np.zeros((1,num_classes))
    '''
    def forward(self, X1):
        '''
        Forward pass through the network

        INPUT
            X: input to network
                shape: (?, 784)

        RETURN
            Y_hat: prediction from output of network 
                shape: (?, 10)
        '''
        Z1 = np.add(np.matmul(X,W1), b1)
        X2 =  sigmoid(Z1)# activation function of Z1
        Z2 = np.add(np.matmul(X2,W2), b2)
        Y_hat =  softmax(Z2)

        #return the hypothesis
        return Y_hat

        # store input for backward pass

        # you can basically copy and past what you did in the forward pass above here

        # think about what you need to store for the backward pass

        return 

    def backward(self, Y_hat, Y):
        '''
        Backward pass through network. Update parameters 

        INPUT
            Y_hat: Network predicted 
                shape: (?, 10)

            Y: Correct target
                shape: (?, 10)

        RETURN 
            cost: calculate J for errors 
                type: (float)

        '''

        #Naked Backprop
        dJ_dZ2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dW2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X2), dJ_dZ2)
        dJ_db2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dX2 =  np.matmul(dJ_db2, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dX2 * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        inner_mat = np.matmul(Y-Y_hat,np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dW1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X),inner_mat) * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        dJ_db1 = np.matmul(Y - Y_hat, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2)) * d_sigmoid(Z1)

        lr = 0.1

        # weight updates here
        #just line 'em up and do lr * the dJ_.. vars you found above
        NeuralNetwork.W2 = NeuralNetwork.W2 - lr * dJ_dW2
        NeuralNetwork.b2 = NeuralNetwork.b2 - lr * dJ_db2
        NeuralNetwork.W1 = NeuralNetwork.W1 - lr * dJ_dW1
        NeuralNetwork.b1 = NeuralNetwork.b1 - lr * dJ_db1

        # calculate the cost
        cost = -1 * np.sum(Y * np.log(Y_hat))

        # calc gradients

        # weight updates

        return cost#, W1, W2, b1, b2

nn = NeuralNetwork(200,10,lr=.01)
num_train = float(len(x_train)) 
num_test = float(len(x_test))

for epoch in range(10):
    train_correct = 0; train_cost = 0
    # training loop
    for i in range(len(x_train)):
        x = x_train[i]; y = y_train[i]
        # standardizing input to range 0 to 1
        X = x.reshape(1,784) /255.

        # forward pass through network
        Y_hat = nn.forward(X)

        # get pred number
        pred_num = np.argmax(Y_hat)

        # check if prediction was accurate
        if pred_num == y:
            train_correct += 1

        # make a one hot categorical vector; same as keras.utils.to_categorical()
        zeros = np.zeros(10); zeros[y] = 1
        Y = zeros

        # compute gradients and update weights
        train_cost += nn.backward(Y_hat, Y)

    test_correct = 0
    # validation loop
    for i in range(len(x_test)):
        x = x_test[i]; y = y_test[i]
        # standardizing input to range 0 to 1
        X = x.reshape(1,784) /255.

        # forward pass
        Y_hat = nn.forward(X)

        # get pred number
        pred_num = np.argmax(Y_hat)

        # check if prediction was correct
        if pred_num == y:
            test_correct += 1

        # no backward pass here!

    # compute average metrics for train and test
    train_correct = round(100*(train_correct/num_train), 2)
    test_correct = round(100*(test_correct/num_test ), 2)
    train_cost = round( train_cost/num_train, 2)

    # print status message every epoch
    log_message = 'Epoch: {epoch}, Train Accuracy: {train_acc}%, Train Cost: {train_cost}, Test Accuracy: {test_acc}%'.format(
        epoch=epoch, 
        train_acc=train_correct, 
        train_cost=train_cost, 
        test_acc=test_correct
    )
    print (log_message)
```

also, The project is in [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OnL7v1zU2xXOgQn5qiPbm45NFOIBJAfV/view?usp=sharing) colab & ipynb notebook

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is pretty clear, in this part of your loop:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    train_correct = 0; train_cost = 0
    # training loop
    for i in range(len(x_train)):
        x = x_train[i]; y = y_train[i]
        # standardizing input to range 0 to 1
        X = x.reshape(1,784) /255.

        # forward pass through network
        Y_hat = nn.forward(X)

        # get pred number
        pred_num = np.argmax(Y_hat)

        # check if prediction was accurate
        if pred_num == y:
            train_correct += 1

        # make a one hot categorical vector; same as keras.utils.to_categorical()
        zeros = np.zeros(10); zeros[y] = 1
        Y = zeros

        # compute gradients and update weights
        train_cost += nn.backward(Y_hat, Y)

    test_correct = 0
    # validation loop
    for i in range(len(x_test)):
        x = x_test[i]; y = y_test[i]
        # standardizing input to range 0 to 1
        X = x.reshape(1,784) /255.

        # forward pass
        Y_hat = nn.forward(X)

        # get pred number
        pred_num = np.argmax(Y_hat)

        # check if prediction was correct
        if pred_num == y:
            test_correct += 1

        # no backward pass here!

    # compute average metrics for train and test
    train_correct = round(100*(train_correct/num_train), 2)
    test_correct = round(100*(test_correct/num_test ), 2)
    train_cost = round( train_cost/num_train, 2)

    # print status message every epoch
    log_message = 'Epoch: {epoch}, Train Accuracy: {train_acc}%, Train Cost: {train_cost}, Test Accuracy: {test_acc}%'.format(
        epoch=epoch, 
        train_acc=train_correct, 
        train_cost=train_cost, 
        test_acc=test_correct
    )
    print (log_message)
```

For every epoch of the 10 epochs in your loop, you are setting your `train_correct` and `train_cost` to 0, hence there is no updating after each `epoch`

Comment: Hey Celius, I tried moving the 'train_correct', and 'test_cost' outside of the for loop but I still end up with the static accuracy

Comment: You needn't just move them out, you probably aren't making them update within your loop. Make sure that is done, then your accuracy will probably update too.

Comment: I am updating the weights in the loop because in the backprop method I am subtracting the gradient * the learning rate from the past weight/bias.